# Shortcut to switch between Rendered View, Material View & Solid View?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

At the moment, I have to go down at the header to keep on changing views in my 3d view port. I would like to speed up my workflow, could you help me out and let me know what is the shortcut to switch between Render View, Material View * Solid View?

Thank you,
W

Comment: Well here is what just happened to me. I switched languages for my keyboard without wanting to. Maybe this is what happened to you. So the Z key is no longer Z. With the Windows Shortcut Alt+Spacebar that happens quiet a lot to me. Hope this was it. Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To switch between different viewport shading

- Press <kbd>Z</kbd> - Wireframe
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - *Render View*
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - *Texture View*

For *Solid* view its a toggle key. When you press same key (repeat key) it will turn to *Solid View*.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Any idea for the shortcut to see materials in 3d view.

Answer (score 4):

If you enable the *Pie Menu* add-on that comes with blender (UI Pie Menu Official) you can use the shortcut <kbd>Z</kbd> (while your cursor is in the 3D view) and then do a gesture towards the render mode you would like to choose. Releasing the <kbd>Z</kbd> key after gesturing towards the option you want chooses that option.

Comment: I didn't know you can do the press-hold-move-release, thanks. I just hit Z (or in my case, Shift+Z), move the mouse, and click.

Answer (score 1):

for the Material View, you have to manually edit it in the User Preferences as in this link: http://www.oneminutevideotutorials.com/2017/06/17/toggle-between-material-viewport-shading-in-blender/